# Something wrong when I select UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

When I select a UITableViewCell the background become gray, the the gray height is strange. Some of the cell is strange like it.I set seperator line style to none. And I add labels to the front and foot cell ,so there are lines between cell.As is show In the first picture.
The other cells are normal as what I expect showed in the second picture.

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

Comment: 2 down votes... u'd better offer some sample code snippets, like how u setup ur cell, especially ur selected background view.

Comment: Are you using custom cell?

Comment: Yes,I inherent the uitablviewcell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have solve the problem. 
First set the :

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

and the overwrite the method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (highlighted) {
        self.contentView.backgroudColor= [UIColor gray];
    } else {
        self.contentView.backgroudColor= [UIColor white];
    }
}
```